# how to find the last dynamic button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have created a dynamic buttons each button is the same:

```
<input type="button" id="editBtn" value="Edit" style="float: right" />//each button has its id ofcourse
```

When one button is pressed it shows a table.
I am looking for a way to 'click last button'/'hide the table' if an other button on page is clicked.

Using Jquery, is it possible ? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: somewhat confusing.! explain a bit more.

Comment: you mean click the `a` button then the table show,and when click the `b` button the table hide?

Comment: yes! when click b - button, b-button table shown and a-button table hide, cant have 2 tables shown at the same time.

Comment: @user2560521 even if you are creating dynamic button give them different id and then assign to it the table what u want to display....u can use this.id to access the button

Answer (score 1):

If u want to display content using button(hide/show)

You can accomplish this using jquery  [toogle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").click(function()
    {
        $("#table").toggle();
    });
});
```

link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUXyx/)

Comment: i need the last table not to be shown.. not the one belongs to the clicked button

Answer (score 1):

Simply hide all siblings of the selected table...

So for example, if you have (Pseudo code)

```
<input type="button" id="editBtn1" value="Edit" onclick="showTable(1)" />
<input type="button" id="editBtn2" value="Edit" onclick="showTable(2)" />
<input type="button" id="editBtn3" value="Edit" onclick="showTable(3)" />

<table id="table1">...</table>
<table id="table2">...</table>
<table id="table3">...</table>
```

JS would be :

```
function showTable(tableid) {
    $("#table" + tableid).show().siblings().hide();
}
```

But of course, this is all very hard coded & hence an avoidable practice.

---

Or as discussed in comments :

```
function showTable() {

    var tableId = $(this).index();

    $("table").hide().eq(tableId).show();
}
```

Comment: sorry cant do this hard coded, in think about something like - if this clicked find the last clicked and close it (click it again for closing) but i cant find a way to write it exectly..

Comment: it can also be like.. hide all & show the one clicked. No need to remember the last one..

Comment: sounds fit.. how to do this?

Comment: as updated above. Hides all tables & shows the table equivalent to the clicked button's index.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved your problem try this fiddle ...

```
  See output on below fiddle
```

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUXyx/75/)

Style:

```
.tbl{
 display:none;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
  $(".btn").click(function(){
  var $this = $(this).next("table");
  $( this ).next("table").removeClass("tbl"); 
  $(".btn").next("table").not($this).addClass("tbl");
  });
```

Html:

```
 <div class="tble">
  <input type="button"  value="Button1" class="btn"/>
  <table class="tbl"><tr><td>test1</td></tr></table>
 </div> 

 <div class="tble">
  <input type="button"  value="Button2" class="btn" /> 
  <table class="tbl"><tr><td>test2</td></tr></table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/BY27P/9/

This will remember the tables you have viewed and let you view all previous ones using basic JavaScript array push/pop.

Here is the JavaScript (view fiddle for full code):

```
var viewedTableHistory = [];

hideAllTables=function(){
    $('table[id^="table"]').hide();  //hide all tables
}

loadTable=function(id){
    viewedTableHistory.push(id);
    $('#history').text(viewedTableHistory);
    hideAllTables();
    showCurrentTable();
};

hideCurrentTable=function()
{
    $('#table'+viewedTableHistory[viewedTableHistory.length-1]).hide();
};

showCurrentTable=function()
{
    $('#table'+viewedTableHistory[viewedTableHistory.length-1]).show();
};

viewPrevTable=function()
{
    hideAllTables();
    viewedTableHistory.pop();
    $('#history').text(viewedTableHistory);
    if(viewedTableHistory.length===0) alert('You are back to the beginning.');
    showCurrentTable();
};
```